# How to make git insert SHAs into conflicted file instead of commit comments?

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

When I rebase and a conflict arises, the conflicted file looks like this:

```
<<<<<<< c50c817dad7008a3760241084de2b83fd4f84288
it was on master 456
=======
it was on master 123
>>>>>>> branch - set up README conflict
```

Sometimes other people don't make such great commit messages, so I might wind up with something like this:

```
<<<<<<< c50c817dad7008a3760241084de2b83fd4f84288
it was on master 456
=======
it was on master 123
>>>>>>> fixed stuff
```

The problem with this is that if there are more than one "fixed stuff" commits, I'll have trouble finding the exact commit. Is there a way I can make git always use SHA hashes instead of commit messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

Well, on the other hand: yes, sort of: use a detached HEAD and cherry pick commits manually, by ID so that git doesn't have a name it can substitute-in.  That defeats much of the purpose of rebase though (rebase automates the cherry-picking, plus the branch-name update at the end).

You shouldn't *need* to do this for two reasons, though.  The one you can't control is that people should not be using crappy commit messages. :-)  The one you *can* use is that when rebase stops with a conflict, `HEAD` and `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` identify the SHA-1s of the two conflicting commits.  See [the `git cherry-pick` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) for details.

(I also recommend setting `merge.conflictstyle` to `diff3`, which lets you see the base version.  It's not as necessary for rebase/cherry-pick as for full merges, but I like it.)